# move textview on finger touch as drag and drop:android

Tags: android

i friends.. 
i am able to move image using finger touch over a view but now i want to move text view rather then image but unable to do that..can i treat text view as image ..means if ill be able to convert text-view in to image then i will pass image object ..my code for moving  image in view are below:

```
      public class MainGamePanel extends SurfaceView implements
    SurfaceHolder.Callback {

private static final String TAG = MainGamePanel.class.getSimpleName();

private MainThread thread;
private Droid droid;

public MainGamePanel(Context context) {
    super(context);
    // adding the callback (this) to the surface holder to intercept events
    getHolder().addCallback(this);

    // create droid and load bitmap
    droid = new Droid(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.droid_1), 50, 50);

    // create the game loop thread
    thread = new MainThread(getHolder(), this);

    // make the GamePanel focusable so it can handle events
    setFocusable(true);
}

@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
        int height) {
}

@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    // at this point the surface is created and
    // we can safely start the game loop
    thread.setRunning(true);
    thread.start();
}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Surface is being destroyed");
    // tell the thread to shut down and wait for it to finish
    // this is a clean shutdown
    boolean retry = true;
    while (retry) {
        try {
            thread.join();
            retry = false;
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // try again shutting down the thread
        }
    }
    Log.d(TAG, "Thread was shut down cleanly");
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        // delegating event handling to the droid
        droid.handleActionDown((int)event.getX(), (int)event.getY());

        // check if in the lower part of the screen we exit
        if (event.getY() > getHeight() - 50) {
            thread.setRunning(false);
            ((Activity)getContext()).finish();
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "Coords: x=" + event.getX() + ",y=" + event.getY());
        }
    } if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
        // the gestures
        if (droid.isTouched()) {
            // the droid was picked up and is being dragged
            droid.setX((int)event.getX());
            droid.setY((int)event.getY());
        }
    } if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        // touch was released
        if (droid.isTouched()) {
            droid.setTouched(false);
        }
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    // fills the canvas with black
    canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
    droid.draw(canvas);
}
```

}

Answer (score 11):

A simple way to accomplish this is by adding an `OnTouchListener` to your `TextView` to move the view to the location of move events.

```
moveableText.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
            // Offsets are for centering the TextView on the touch location
            v.setX(event.getRawX() - v.getWidth() / 2.0f);
            v.setY(event.getRawY() - v.getHeight() / 2.0f);
        }
            
        return true;
    }
        
});
```

This should be exact for a fullscreen activity with no title bar, but otherwise you may need to subtract the height of your title bar (and possibly notification bar) from the y-coordinate.

Comment: this code works fine. But the drag point i a little above the text view

Comment: thank you very much! This worked as a charm for me :))

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to make a TextView move only horizontally, the code above really helped me but it looked kind of wobbly because the middle of the textview always went to the finger. So I changed the code a little bit to make it look more natural:

```
float diffFingerMove = 0;
private void moveViewOnFinger(View view, MotionEvent event){
    float fingerPos = event.getRawX();

    if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
        diffFingerMove = fingerPos - view.getX();
    }
    view.setX(fingerPos - diffFingerMove);
}
```